# How to escape a URL for Elasticsearch?

Tags: java, url, elasticsearch

In one of my fields in Elasticsearch I'm storing the URL of my documents (e.g. `http://techcrunch.com/something-great`)

When I don't escape the URL, the document is found correctly - but I get the EOF error on some URLs.

When I escape the URL with:

```
String escapedString = QueryParser.escape(e.getKey().getUrl());
```

The document is not found - I get zero hits.

So how to do it?

---

```
    {
    _index: "crawlbot",
    _type: "article",
    _id: "AVFaaFu4w49jUzVInKS5",
    _score: 1,
    _source: {
        job: {
            id: 65,
            name: "wikipedia_en",
            max_pages: 300000,
            crawl_depth: 0,
            processing_patterns: "-Category,-User,-Wikipedia:,-Topic,-Special:,-Talk:,-Portal:,-MOS",
            status: 0,
            days: 0,
            url: [
                "https://en.wikipedia.org"
            ],
            ajax: false,
            min_description: 0
        },
        article: {
            url: "https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?action=history&feed=atom&title=Parliament_of_Romania",
            provider_url: "https://en.wikipedia.org",
            provider_name: "",
            provider_display: "en.wikipedia.org",
            favicon_url: "http://www.google.com/s2/u/0/favicons?domain=https://en.wikipedia.org",
            language: "en",
            metadata: {
                authors: []
            },
            entities: [],
            keywords: [],
            videos: [],
            unfilteredKeywords: [],
            published: "",
            published_long: 0
        }
    }
}
```

And i would like the to retrieve the document per article.url

This is the query:

```
 SearchRequestBuilder requestBuilder = client.prepareSearch("crawlbot").setSearchType(SearchType.DFS_QUERY_THEN_FETCH);
            BoolQueryBuilder queryBuilder = new BoolQueryBuilder();
            String escapedString = QueryParser.escape(e.getKey().getUrl());
            queryBuilder.must(QueryBuilders.queryStringQuery(escapedString).defaultField("article.url"));
            queryBuilder.must(QueryBuilders.queryStringQuery(e.getKey().getJob().getId() + "").defaultField("job.id"));
```

Error if i don't escape:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.elasticsearch.action.search.SearchPhaseExecutionException: Failed to execute phase [query], all shards failed; shardFailures {[9_T8APppReyWKppSNZWmXw][crawlbot][0]: SearchParseException[[crawlbot][0]: from[-1],size[-1]: Parse Failure [Failed to parse source [{"query":{"bool":{"must":[{"query_string":{"query":"http://www.zeit.de/wirtschaft/2015-11/griechenland-reparationszahlung-bayern-rentner-jahresrueckblick-2?page=4","default_field":"article.url"}},{"query_string":{"query":"70","default_field":"job.id"}}]}}}]]]; nested: QueryParsingException[[crawlbot] Failed to parse query [http://www.zeit.de/wirtschaft/2015-11/griechenland-reparationszahlung-bayern-rentner-jahresrueckblick-2?page=4]]; nested: ParseException[Cannot parse 'http://www.zeit.de/wirtschaft/2015-11/griechenland-reparationszahlung-bayern-rentner-jahresrueckblick-2?page=4': Lexical error at line 1, column 111.  Encountered: <EOF> after : "/griechenland-reparationszahlung-bayern-rentner-jahresrueckblick-2?page=4"]; nested: TokenMgrError[Lexical error at line 1, column 111.  Encountered: <EOF> after : "/griechenland-reparationszahlung-bayern-rentner-jahresrueckblick-2?page=4"]; }{[9_T8APppReyWKppSNZWmXw][crawlbot][1]: SearchParseException[[crawlbot][1]: from[-1],size[-1]: Parse Failure [Failed to parse source [{"query":{"bool":{"must":[{"query_string":{"query":"http://www.zeit.de/wirtschaft/2015-11/griechenland-reparationszahlung-bayern-rentner-jahresrueckblick-2?page=4","default_field":"article.url"}},{"query_string":{"query":"70","default_field":"job.id"}}]}}}]]]; nested: QueryParsingException[[crawlbot] Failed to parse query [http://www.zeit.de/wirtschaft/2015-11/griechenland-reparationszahlung-bayern-rentner-jahresrueckblick-2?page=4]]; nested: ParseException[Cannot parse 'http://www.zeit.de/wirtschaft/2015-11/griechenland-reparationszahlung-bayern-rentner-jahresrueckblick-2?page=4': Lexical error at line 1, column 111.  Encountered: <EOF> after : "/griechenland-reparationszahlung-bayern-rentner-jahresrueckblick-2?page=4"]; nested: TokenMgrError[Lexical error at line 1, column 111.  Encountered: <EOF> after : "/griechenland-reparationszahlung-bayern-rentner-jahresrueckblick-2?page=4"]; }{[9_T8APppReyWKppSNZWmXw][crawlbot][2]: SearchParseException[[crawlbot][2]: from[-1],size[-1]: Parse Failure [Failed to parse source [{"query":{"bool":{"must":[{"query_string":{"query":"http://www.zeit.de/wirtschaft/2015-11/griechenland-reparationszahlung-bayern-rentner-jahresrueckblick-2?page=4","default_field":"article.url"}},{"query_string":{"query":"70","default_field":"job.id"}}]}}}]]]; nested: QueryParsingException[[crawlbot] Failed to parse query [http://www.zeit.de/wirtschaft/2015-11/griechenland-reparationszahlung-bayern-rentner-jahresrueckblick-2?page=4]]; nested: ParseException[Cannot parse 'http://www.zeit.de/wirtschaft/2015-11/griechenland-reparationszahlung-bayern-rentner-jahresrueckblick-2?page=4': Lexical error at line 1, column 111.  Encountered: <EOF> after : "/griechenland-reparationszahlung-bayern-rentner-jahresrueckblick-2?page=4"]; nested: TokenMgrError[Lexical error at line 1, column 111.  Encountered: <EOF> after : "/griechenland-reparationszahlung-bayern-rentner-jahresrueckblick-2?page=4"]; }{[9_T8APppReyWKppSNZWmXw][crawlbot][3]: SearchParseException[[crawlbot][3]: from[-1],size[-1]: Parse Failure [Failed to parse source [{"query":{"bool":{"must":[{"query_string":{"query":"http://www.zeit.de/wirtschaft/2015-11/griechenland-reparationszahlung-bayern-rentner-jahresrueckblick-2?page=4","default_field":"article.url"}},{"query_string":{"query":"70","default_field":"job.id"}}]}}}]]]; nested: QueryParsingException[[crawlbot] Failed to parse query [http://www.zeit.de/wirtschaft/2015-11/griechenland-reparationszahlung-bayern-rentner-jahresrueckblick-2?page=4]]; nested: ParseException[Cannot parse 'http://www.zeit.de/wirtschaft/2015-11/griechenland-reparationszahlung-bayern-rentner-jahresrueckblick-2?page=4': Lexical error at line 1, column 111.  Encountered: <EOF> after : "/griechenland-reparationszahlung-bayern-rentner-jahresrueckblick-2?page=4"]; nested: TokenMgrError[Lexical error at line 1, column 111.  Encountered: <EOF> after : "/griechenland-reparationszahlung-bayern-rentner-jahresrueckblick-2?page=4"]; }{[9_T8APppReyWKppSNZWmXw][crawlbot][4]: SearchParseException[[crawlbot][4]: from[-1],size[-1]: Parse Failure [Failed to parse source [{"query":{"bool":{"must":[{"query_string":{"query":"http://www.zeit.de/wirtschaft/2015-11/griechenland-reparationszahlung-bayern-rentner-jahresrueckblick-2?page=4","default_field":"article.url"}},{"query_string":{"query":"70","default_field":"job.id"}}]}}}]]]; nested: QueryParsingException[[crawlbot] Failed to parse query [http://www.zeit.de/wirtschaft/2015-11/griechenland-reparationszahlung-bayern-rentner-jahresrueckblick-2?page=4]]; nested: ParseException[Cannot parse 'http://www.zeit.de/wirtschaft/2015-11/griechenland-reparationszahlung-bayern-rentner-jahresrueckblick-2?page=4': Lexical error at line 1, column 111.  Encountered: <EOF> after : "/griechenland-reparationszahlung-bayern-rentner-jahresrueckblick-2?page=4"]; nested: TokenMgrError[Lexical error at line 1, column 111.  Encountered: <EOF> after : "/griechenland-reparationszahlung-bayern-rentner-jahresrueckblick-2?page=4"]; }
    at org.elasticsearch.action.search.type.TransportSearchTypeAction$BaseAsyncAction.onFirstPhaseResult(TransportSearchTypeAction.java:237)
    at org.elasticsearch.action.search.type.TransportSearchTypeAction$BaseAsyncAction$1.onFailure(TransportSearchTypeAction.java:183)
    at org.elasticsearch.search.action.SearchServiceTransportAction$23.run(SearchServiceTransportAction.java:565)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: Can you provide a sample document/URL, so it's easier to picture what your problem is?

Comment: Added it - hope that helps ;)

Comment: Ok, thanks, and now what is the mapping of the `article.url` field (i.e. is that a `not_analyzed` string field)? Why do you escape the URL in your query and how does your query look like?

Comment: I think i need to escape the urls because of the slashes. If i don't do that i get an error ;) Thanks for your help so far

Comment: What is the mapping of your `article.url` field?

Comment: url: {
type: "string"
},

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you change the mapping of your `article.url` field to:

```
url: {
    "type": "string",
    "index": "not_analyzed"
}
```

Failing to do so will make your field analyzed and very hard to query given the way the standard analyzer will break up the URL into several tokens.

Then, instead of using a `query_string` query, you can use a `term` query in order to query your documents.

```
SearchRequestBuilder requestBuilder = client.prepareSearch("crawlbot").setSearchType(SearchType.DFS_QUERY_THEN_FETCH);
BoolQueryBuilder queryBuilder = new BoolQueryBuilder();
queryBuilder.must(QueryBuilders.termQuery("article.url", e.getKey().getUrl()));
...                                 ^
                                    |
                        use a term query instead
```

**UPDATE**

Following up on Evaldas' comment (kudos Evaldas!), in the end the idea is to create a custom analyzer in order to make sure that the URL will be lowercased as well.

When creating your index, you can add a new analyzer in the `settings` and then use it as the analyzer of your `article.url` field:

```
PUT /crawlbot
{
    "settings": {
        "analysis": {
            "analyzer": {
                "url_analyzer": {
                    "type":         "custom",
                    "tokenizer":    "keyword",
                    "filter":       [ "lowercase" ]
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "mappings": {
        "article": {
            "properties": {
                "article": {
                    "url": {
                        "type": "string",
                        "analyzer": "url_analyzer"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: As always, I would go for `keyword` tokenizer + `lowercase` filter. Just to make this case insensitive instead of having field `not_analyzed`.

Comment: @EvaldasBuinauskas can you evaluate on that? ;) Maybe give a short example too

Val -  Thanks for your answer. I will check it out soon!

Comment: Agreed, though I wanted to proceed step-by-step with this one. But in the end, it's correct.

Comment: @FabianLurz Val has just added it!

Comment: Thanks, feel free, indeed!