# Finding a document with a specific term on an array

Tags: arrays, elasticsearch

I'm trying to find a document containing a specific term in an array of strings.

I have a schema like this:

```
{
  "pages": {
    "mappings":{
      "site":{
        "properties":{
          "urls":{"type":"string"}
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And the following data indexed on it:

```
% curl -XPOST 'http://local.dev:9200/pages/site/_search?pretty
{
  ...
  "hits" : {
    "total" : 1,
    "max_score" : 1.0,
    "hits" : [ {
      "_index" : "pages",
      "_type" : "site",
      "_id" : "ae634fea-878f-42ca-8239-c67cca007a38",
      "_score" : 1.0,
      "_source":{ "urls":["https://github.com/fulano","http://fulano.com"] }
    } 
  }
```

I'm trying to search for sites whose urls array contains a specific url, but I can't make it work. I tried using [terms](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-terms-query.html) - exactly as described [here](http://www.tugberkugurlu.com/archive/elasticsearch-array-contains-search-with-terms-filter) but I never get any results:

```
% curl -XPOST 'http://local.dev:9200/pages/site/_search?pretty' -d '
{
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
        "filter": {
            "term": { "urls": "https://github.com/fulano" }
        }
    }
  }
}'
{
  "hits" : {
    "total" : 0,
    "max_score" : null,
    "hits" : [ ]
  }
}
```

Using terms (that gets expanded into a series of bool operations by elastic):

```
% curl -XPOST 'http://local.dev:9200/pages/site/_search?pretty' -d '
{
  "query": {
    "terms" : {
        "urls" : ["https://github.com/fulano"]
    }
  }
}'
{
  "hits" : {
    "total" : 0,
    "max_score" : null,
    "hits" : [ ]
  }
}
```

I'm guessing this is something really silly, but I can't spot the problem. :(

Comment: This [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34133218/how-to-escape-a-url-for-elasticsearch/34135587#34135587) shows exactly what you need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the problem with the analyzer you are using. You need to use not_analyzed or keyword tokenizer as outlined [here](http://blog.qbox.io/elasticsearch-aggregation-custom-analyzer).