# Searching for uris in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I have some data in elasticsearch, and when querying with

```
{
  "query": {"match_all": {}}
}
```

I get one document returned:

```
"hits": [{ ...
        "_source": {
          "uri": "/",
          "templateId": "frontpage",
        ... }
      }]
```

My problem is that I can't seem to query the document by it's `uri` field.
Whereas query with

`{"term": { "templateId": "frontpage" }}`

is working as expected, I get no results querying like this:

```
POST http://localhost:9200/cms/page/_search
{
  "query" : {
    "term" : { "uri" : "/" }
  }
}
```

I have also tried escaping the input, `\/` according to the documentation and `\\\/`, but still no results. I'd really appreciate if you could point me in the right direction in order to escape my search input correctly.

Comment: Please share the mapping of your index. `GET /index_name/type_name/_mapping`

Comment: I just figured this out, and it was because I hadn't created a specific mapping for the uri field. I eventually found this question that got me going: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34133218/how-to-escape-a-url-for-elasticsearch
Thanks :)